# how to call function in bloc pattern flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have class required Function for delete named hapusCart.

I have bloc like this

```
Stream<List<KotakKeranjang>> mapEventToState(int event) async* {
    List<KotakKeranjang> kotakBanyak = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < event; i++)
      kotakBanyak.add(KotakKeranjang(
          nama: 'nama ' + i.toString(),
          price: ((i + 1) * 5000).toString(),
          jumlah: '3',
          hapuscart: () {}));
    yield kotakBanyak;
  }
```

and the output for listview builder

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: kotakKeranjang.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      KotakKeranjang(
                        nama: '${kotakKeranjang[index].nama}',
                        price: '${kotakKeranjang[index].price}',
                        jumlah: '${kotakKeranjang[index].jumlah}',
                        hapuscart: () {kotakkeranjang.removeAt(index);},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

I want to delete specific data in that list, I had try

```
kotakkeranjang.removeAt(index);
```

but it's not working. can anyone help?

Comment: where you put the `removeAt(index)`?

Comment: @JohnJoe in listviewbuilder method hapuscart

Comment: please update your post by adding the delete method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `setState` to refresh the `listView`.

```
  setState(() {
      kotakkeranjang.removeAt(index);
  });
```

Comment: thank you sir, but i have this error "setState() or markNeedsBuild()  
called during build.This ProductPage2 widget cannot be marked as needing to build   
because the framework is already in the process of building widgets."

Comment: maybe we need see more code. Can show us your `widget build` and `KotakKeranjang` ?

Comment: @walidthalib that markNeedsBuild() error means you had unnecessary notifiylistener() somewhere in your project. Check exactyle where that error shows up and remove it then it will be fixed

Comment: @MiraçKılıç  and john joe,, yes sir finally it fixed after remove unnecessary setState , thank you sir !!